# UITableView background image for all cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib

I want to change my tableview background image. When i change it, the change doesn't effect the cells. I'm using xib for my cells which doesn't have any code inside it, just design. So how can i solve this?

```
    self.list.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pattern.png"]];
```

[image: tableview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, set your cell's background color to clear color. It will make your cells transparent and show the background image.

**Objective C:**

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

**Swift:**

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```